# SpecFlow works only with en-US In Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, specflow

I tried to start developing with SpecFlow using BDD paradigm. Everything seems to work fine, if I'm using `@language en-US`. After changing to pl-PL, code generation crashes with error as in code snippets below:

```
Funkcja: PolishGenerator
    Ten feature opisalem po polsku

#error (3:1): expected: #TagLine, #FeatureLine, #Comment, #Empty, got 'Funkcja: PolishGenerator'
#error (4:2): expected: #TagLine, #FeatureLine, #Comment, #Empty, got 'Ten feature opisalem po polsku'
#error (5:0): unexpected end of file, expected: #TagLine, #FeatureLine, #Comment, #Empty
```

However, this works fine:

```
@language en-US
Feature: SpecFlowFeature1
    In order to avoid silly mistakes
```

After long session of googling, I only found encoding-related error in French language, however, even if I use only ASCII-compatible characters(no accents, special letters) it ends with same error. Also, file is properly encoded using standard UTF-8-BOM.

I've double-checked with gherking-languages.json if I'm using proper words, and yes, they seem to be OK.

I'm using SpecFlow 2.2.1 as nuget package along with Visual Studio 2015 Professional Update 3 and SpecFlow for Visual Studio 2015 version 2017.1.6

Comment: Could you post a complete project somewhere? It would be much easier to find the problem.

Comment: I'm afraid not. This is closed source. I had to drop Specflow from project, as we simply couldn't afford the time to fix this. Also we migrated to Visual Studio 2017 shortly after.